# CoreData-Project with two entities

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I've two tableViews in my app and the user should be able add objects to both of them. With one tableView it works fine (there's only one coreData **entity**). But when I add another entity and do the same things as with just one tableView, xcode shows me an error.

The output is:

```
 Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x10333d80 {metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Buy = <883135e4 2884b0ed 4bb8fc1c 7d56c229 fbae3090 91be719d 73ac5d66 65e70b18>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "...";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Buy = <883135e4 2884b0ed 4bb8fc1c 7d56c229 fbae3090 91be719d 73ac5d66 65e70b18>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "...";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
(lldb)
```

I've tried to solve this for hours, but I did the same thing in the second tableView as in the first.

Maybe someone could help me. Thanks in advancen

Comment: Did you search for the "The model used to open the store is incompatible ..." error message? There should be some hits...

Answer (score 0):

When you're designing your model you need to do a migration:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

So the first thing you should do is create a new model version.

For things like adding fields and entities coredata can do this automatically via lightweight migration.  For more complicated things you'll need to create a mapping model.

If your app isn't in the store and doesn't have any users you don't really need to worry about migration at all.  Just delete the app off the phone/simulator and run your app.  If you do have the app in the store you absolutely must specify a new model version and do a migration.